# How to convert Python bytes string representation to bytes?

Tags: python

I have a number of Python bytes objects stored in a text file, that Python prints like `"b'\x80\x03}q\x00.'"` How do I convert each of these back into a bytes object?

In other words, I'm trying to find a function that does `convert("b'\x80\x03}q\x00.'") == b'\x80\x03}q\x00.'`.

I feel like this should be trivial, but none of these obvious approaches worked:

```
>>> s = "b'\x80\x03}q\x00.'"
>>> bytes(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
>>> bytes(s.encode())
b"b'\xc2\x80\x03}q\x00.'"
>>> bytes(s[2:-1].encode())
b'\xc2\x80\x03}q\x00.'
>>> bytes(s[2:-1].encode('utf8'))
b'\xc2\x80\x03}q\x00.'
>>> eval(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
>>> exec(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Comment: You have string representations of `bytes` literals, not `bytes` objects. How did this file get created in the first place?

Comment: Actually, you don't quite have a `bytes` literal. With `s = "..."`, `\x00`, for example, is replace with an actual null byte, rather than remaining the 4 characters that represent a null byte in a literal. If you write `s = r"..."`, then `ast.literal_eval(s)` returns the `bytes` object you want.

Comment: That's specific to how you set `s` in this example; if `s` is read from a file, like e.g. `s = f.readline()`, this isn't an issue.

Comment: s = "b'\x80\x03}q\x00.'"  is a string then this should work str.encode(s)

Comment: `bytes(s[2:-1].encode())[1:]  # b'\x80\x03}q\x00.'`

Comment: I think you should not convert `byte-string` to `string` in the first place! It's better to `decode` it. i.e. `bs = b'\x80\x03}q\x00.'` then you sould write `s = bs.decode()` so you can convert it back to byte-string whenever you want with `s.encode()` :)

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't really apply to the case where the value of `s` is read from a file, but in your example, the regular string literal expands the escape sequences:

```
>>> s = "b'\x80\x03}q\x00.'"
>>> list(s)
['b', "'", '\x80', '\x03', '}', 'q', '\x00', '.', "'"]
```

Note that `s` doesn't contain the escape sequence for a null byte; it contains an *actual* null byte.

You can avoid this using a raw string literal:

```
>>> s = r"b'\x80\x03}q\x00.'"
>>> list(s)
['b', "'", '\\', 'x', '8', '0', '\\', 'x', '0', '3', '}', 'q', '\\', 'x', '0', '0', '.', "'"]
```

in which case `ast.literal_eval` is the function you are looking for:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
b'\x80\x03}q\x00.'
```

The raw string literal should produce the value you would read from a file:

```
import ast

b = b'\x80\x03}q\x00.'

with open("tmp.txt", "w") as f:
    print(str(b), file=f)

with open("tmp.txt") as f:
    s = f.readline().strip()

assert ast.literal_eval(s) == b
```